# istream::read not filling char array correctly

Tags: c++, file-io, binary, istream

I'm opening an istream for binary read:

```
ifstream file;
file.open (this -> fileName.c_str(), ios::binary);
```

I then try to read, while the file is good, into a char array pointer:

```
char data[numberOfBytes];
char * p = data;
file.read(p, numberOfBytes);
cout << "size: "   << sizeof(p)     << end
cout << "gcount: " << file.gcount() << endl;
cout << "strlen: " << strlen(p)     << endl;
```

The output is different for each of the above. Sizeof() produces 4 which is correct size of char pointer. gcount() produces whatever value numberOfBytes has. However, strlen() returns some other smaller number. So, although read() has moved the istream pointer numberOfBytes, I do not have these bytes in the char array. I want all those bytes in the char array. How do I achieve this? What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're reading in binary data then it's possible that you're reading a byte with a value of zero, or a null character in string terminology.

The way strlen() calculates the size of a string is by starting at the beginning of the string, and counting until it reaches a null character.

Thus strlen() will only report the number of bytes up to the null character, not the actual number of bytes read.

Comment: All the answers below are correct. This was my problem: I was sending the data array through a udp socket. On the receiving side, I had to reconstruct (therefore write to istream) but i didn't know how many bytes. I simply added that information to my packet structure and now all is good, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

I only can guess that you have not initialized `numberOfBytes`. I just copied and printed, it is working for me:

```
//file test.C
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream file;
    file.open ("test.C", ios::binary);
    char data[1024];
    char *p = data;
    file.read(p, 1024);
    cout << "size: "   << sizeof(p)     << endl;
    cout << "gcount: " << file.gcount() << endl;
    cout << "strlen: " << strlen(p)     << endl;
    cout << "data: " << p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` reports the number of bytes up till but not including the first nullbyte.

Answer (score 2):

The function `strlen` counts number of bytes until it finds a byte that is zero. Could it be that the data is not all printable charaters?

Answer (score 1):

there might be a `EOF` or `NULL` equivalent in your binary string that is causing problems to `strlen`.